# getting python list of strings into javascript variable via Jinja2 render_template()

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to set a javascript variable in a HTML-document by calling (Jinja2) `render_template('manage_stations.html', stations=stations)`
(The javascript variable should be an array of station names as strings used for an autocomplete functionality):

```
var station_names = ['station1name', 'station2name', 'station3name'];
```

In my python code, the entries of the list *stations[]* are of type **sqlite3.Row**. I only need the ['station_name'] content:

```
stations[0]['station_name'] = 'station1name'
stations[1]['station_name'] = 'station2name' 
stations[2]['station_name'] = 'station3name'
```

etc...

my manage_stations.html file  like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
 <head>
  <script>
     var station_names = {{ [ x['station_name'] for x in stations]|tojson }} ;
  </script>
 </head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

> Exception has occurred: TemplateSyntaxError
> expected token ',', got 'for'

Is it possible to solve this in the html-template?
I had the idea to assemble a string like:

```
l = "'" + "','".join(s['station_name'].replace("'", r"\'") for s in stations) + "'"
```

and then pass it as an additional parameter to the render_template function.
`render_template('manage_stations.html', stations=stations, station_name_string=l)`
But wouldn't it be better to only pass one variable stations (which contains all the neccesary information) and do the formatting somehow?

Thank You!

EDIT:
I just found out that list comprehension is not supported in Jinja2 - is it still possilbe to get the variable set without adding a second parameter?

Answer (score 0):

...one (not the desired) way to solve it is to really add a new parameter, stations_list, and add this:

```
 station_list = [ x['station_name'] for x in stations]  
  

<script>
var station_names =   {{ station_list|safe }}  ;
</script>
```

However, I'm still not sarisfied because I pass two arguments with the same info, only because the formatting can't be done...